# How can two electric plates have a potential difference if the circuit is technically incomplete?

Tags: electric-fields, potential

With two electric plates, for example: [image]

When the switch is closed, wouldn't the circuit still be incomplete? So I'm not too sure as to why there is still able to be a potential difference.

But if the switch is open, there is no potential difference. However if the switch is open, isn't this still the same as the switch being closed because in both cases the switch would be open? ie even if the bottom plate couldn't get polarised, wouldn't the top still be able to gain a negative voltage and in comparison with the neutral bottom plate, still producing a potential difference?

Answer (score 1):

First, it should not be a magnetic field between the plates, but an electric field. And the e- in the middle should be on one of the plates.

The idea of a capacitor (basically two electrically conductive plates arranged close to but not touching eachother) is that electric charge can be unbalanced. There can be extra electrons on one side relative to the other. The capacitor has a very good electrical insulator between. (Air or paper or some chemicals etc.) Thus, this unbalanced charge can take a very long time to discharge. (As anybody who has ever worked with an old-style cathode-ray-tube television is sure to know. ZAP! Ouch!)

Suppose you started with everything drained and the switch open. When the switch is closed, the voltage source pushes electrical charge from one plate to the other. A current begins to flow. This sets up the electric field in the capacitor body. When things reach equilibrium, the electric field is exactly enough to balance the voltage source, and current goes to zero.  If you then open the switch, there is still zero current. The elctrons can't get back to the other side to balance things. Except through the very large resistance between the plates. As previously, this can take a long time. With very good capacitors it can take many hours or even days. (Again, watch out for electronic devices with capacitors that could still be charged. Camera flashes for example.)

If you provided any significant way for the electrons to balance, they would. For example, putting a volt meter across the leads of the capacitor would allow current to flow through the volt meter. A good volt meter will have a quite large resistance, but will still let the charge leak out. If you charge a capacitor, remove the charger, then put the volt meter across the leads, you will see the voltage start at some high value and fall.